# Typescript generics for react component taking array of records and array of keys

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript, generics

I'm trying to create a simple typed react component for rendering a table from an array of objects. The data input is in the format of:

```js
// array of records containing data to render in the table
data = [
  {
    one: 1,
    two: 2,
    three: 3,
  },
  {
    one: 11,
    two: 22,
    three: 33,
  }
]

// subset of keys from the data to render in the table
labels = [
  'one',
  'three',
]
```

The component is as follows:

```js
function Table<T extends Record<string, string | number>, K extends Extract<keyof T, string>>({
    labels,
    data
}: {
    labels: K[];
    data: T[];
}) {
    return (
        <table className="table">
            {/* ... */}
        </table>
    );
}
```

Testing it, it seems to work only when the labels is created in the prop and not before:

```js
// Works
<Table labels={['one']} data={data} />

// Does not work
const labels = ['one']
<Table labels={labels} data={data} />
// Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type '("one" | "two" | "three")'
```

Does anyone know how to fix the typing so that the second method works and I don't have to create the labels array inline?

Answer (score 0):

Typescript will not infer string literal types unless it has to. If you write `const labels = ['one'];` typescript will widen the type of `labels` to `string[]`.

You can get araound this either by using `as const` in 3.4 (unreleased yet) but using `as const` which will make ts infer a read-only tuple for `labels`

```
const labels = ['one'] as const; // const labels: readonly ["one"]
```

Before 3.4 we can either use an explicit type:

```
const labels:  ["one"] = ['one'];
```

Or use an helper function to hint to the compiler  to infer string literal and tuples:

```
function stringTuple<T extends string[]>(...a: T){
    return a;
}
const labels = stringTuple('one'); // const labels:  ["one"]
```

Answer (score 0):

**By defining `Data` first**

```
interface Data {
  one: number,
  two: number,
  three: number,
}

const labels: keyof Data[] = ['one']
```

**By reading the type of Data**

```
const labels: keyof Unpacked<typeof data>[] = ['one']

type Unpacked<T> =
  T extends Array<infer U>
    ? U
    : T;
```

**By using a type assertion**

```
<Table labels={labels as (keyof Data)[]} data={data} />
```